# Migrating changes to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm developing a web app in ASP.NET with Entity Framework and a SQL Server database.

I'm using Code-First approach. Until now everytime I made a change to the database schema (added tables, changed tables rows (add or remove)) the database was recreated. Since it was not a live version yet.

Now, I will deploy the application, while I continue to develop it.

How should I proceed to update a live version of the database with the changes I make locally? That, without losing data.

So, per example, I create a new table and a add or remove a few rows in another tables with a code first approach. Everything is tested and working and now I want to update the live version. How would I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Code First Migrations, check out this [Link to MSDN](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Code first migrations will take the current state and make it 'Initial Migration', all changes from then on are scripted as incremental updates. Your change flow should look like this:

1. Make change (add table through classes, etc etc)
2. Generate a Migration
3. Run the Migration
4. Test the Change
5. Deploy the change to the live system

When you deploy the change, in your publish settings you can inform it to run the migrations on application start up, or on request.